# the effect of an operation

Tags: notation, operations-research

What is the meaning of the line above a function, for example if A=teta or another variable and teta is time dependent. what is the effect of this operation on it? I mean: $\overline{{\bf A}}$
in an equation like this:
if for example d is teta(degree), what is the effect of this operation on d?
[image]

Comment: It could mean a bunch of different things. You are going to have to be more specific about where exactly (which book, what field, so on) you encountered this.

Comment: Could be complex conjugate.

Comment: @DouglasMolin: it's about a time dependent variable and is not about matrices.

Comment: Sometimes it means an average over time.